# How to localize WebGrid column headers from resource file

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, gridview, localization

I have localised the display of property names in my applications by adding the `Display` attribute, which gets the string value from a `resx` file:

```
public class ViewLeadViewModel
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Location", ResourceType = typeof(FormLabels))]
    public string Location { get; set; }
}
```

This works fine in forms and when viewing the data in a basic grid.

However, I want to use a `WebGrid` to dispaly the data, but it seems that the `Display` attribute is not supported, and we can only use `DisplayName` for this (currently the column headers just use the actual name of the property).

I tried adding this attribute:

```
[DisplayName(FormLabels.ResourceManager.GetString("Location"))]
```

But I get the error

> An attribute argument must be a constant expression, typeof expression or array creation expression of an attribute parameter type

How can I localise the column headers in `WebGrid` from a resource file?

---

#### Update

Here is the code in `Index.cshtml`:

```
@model IEnumerable<AuroraWeb.Models.ViewLeadViewModel>

@{ 
    var grid = new WebGrid(new List<object>());

    grid = new WebGrid( Model,
                        rowsPerPage: 100);
}

@grid.GetHtml(
    tableStyle: "table",
    alternatingRowStyle: "alternate")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom attribute class inherited from `DisplayNameAttribute` and set the `DisplayName` string property inside the attribute by providing the resource key, given by this example below:

```
// provided by Brian Schroer
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]
public class LocalizedDisplayNameAttribute : DisplayNameAttribute 
{
    public LocalizedDisplayNameAttribute(string resourceKey)
    {
        ResourceKey = resourceKey;
    }

    private string ResourceKey { get; set; }

    public override string DisplayName
    {
        get
        {
            string displayName = FormLabels.ResourceManager.GetString(ResourceKey);
            return string.IsNullOrEmpty(displayName) ? string.Format("[[{0}]]", ResourceKey) : displayName;
        }
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```
[LocalizedDisplayName("Location")]
public string Location { get; set; }
```

Reference:

[ASP.NET MVC localization DisplayNameAttribute alternatives: a good way](http://geekswithblogs.net/brians/archive/2010/06/14/asp.net-mvc-localization-displaynameattribute-alternatives-a-good-way.aspx)

Comment: Hi Tetsuya thanks forr your answer. I already tried a similar approach, but it still does not work with `WebGrid`. I set a break point in the `DisplayName` class, and can see that the correct localized string is returned, but for some reason `WebGrid` refuses to use that value for the column header

Comment: My apologies, I am actuallly using a `WebGrid`

Comment: Is this `WebGrid` you mean: [System.Web.Helpers.WebGrid](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.helpers.webgrid(v=vs.111).aspx)? And how you're using `WebGrid` in the Razor page?

Comment: I updated my question with the razor code. I believe that is the `WebGrid`, yes

Comment: I think `columns: grid.Columns(grid.Column("columnName", FormLabels.ResourceManager.GetString("key")))` in `grid.GetHtml` method can set the localized header name, but I'm not sure if it works with pulled resource. I found header name usage example in http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/sourabh_mishra1/webgrid-in-Asp-Net-mvc/.